# python selenium ide generated unittest, exporting using nose (xunit) with multiple cases using same browser

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, jenkins, nose

So the code below is a webdriver python code generated from selenium ide on firefox. I have some other code that is generated but its very long and i wanted to keep this simple and short.

So my problem is that i want to generate a test case for each line in the test_ function but i need it to go in order, i don't want to create multiple test functions. So i have tried doing using the yield functionality ( explained here http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html) but it doesn't get passed loading the web browser up. It's kinda hard to explain since i don't have my actual code below.

I will be exporting the results using nosetests --with-xunit and then letting Jenkins deal with the xml. When i run the code now and look at the xml, it only contains one large block of text from the output and thats all in one tag, its not separated.

So is there a way to generate separate test cases but still go through the instructions sequentially. One solution i have is that i could send in the first instruction (driver.get(self.base_url + "/")), then do that first one and the second one, then first, second, third. But I don't think that is the best way.

Also i know about assertions and most of the stuff about unittest, i just need a way to have each web browser action be a test case but not close the browser when it finishes each case, i need it to keep one browser open and go through each action like it would if you played it through selenium's ide on firefox.

Maybe i am looking at my problem wrong, or coding it wrong.

Here is the generated code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.ca/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("nba")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("NBA.com").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Tickets").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Stats").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

here is what i want it to do (with pseudo code):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.ca/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_(self):
        driver = self.driver 

        #run the instruction below and add it to the list of tests
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")

        #if the previous instruction was successful, run the one below and add it to the list
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()

        #do the same
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("nba")

        #etc, you get the idea...hopefully :)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("NBA.com").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Tickets").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Stats").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

the output would look like this if it runs the way i want it to run:

```
Website loaded google.ca ... ok  
element found lst-ib and cleared ... ok  
element found lst-ib and sent keys nba ... ok
element found nba.com and clicked ... ok
element found tickets and clicked ... ok
element found stats and clicked ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 5.0s
```

currently looks like this:

```
loaded google, searched and clicked nba.com, clicked tickets and then starts... ok      

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 5.0s
```

in the xml is just one large block and it doesn't look good, nor does it give good feedback on the tests

thanks for any help :)

--------update--------------

seems like i didn't explain the problem well enough

so what i want the code to do is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.ca/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_one(self):
        driver = self.driver             
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")

    def test_two(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()

    def test_three(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("nba")

    def test_four(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("NBA.com").click()

    def test_five(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Tickets").click()

    def test_six(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Stats").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

in the situation above the xml file that would be created would have 6 different entries, but it doesn't do what i need it to do since it creates a new browser every time it starts the test. I need it to create the 6 cases but not close the browser. thinking about it now i could probably some how remove the setup from the test functions

Comment: There is an example on how to get started here https://github.com/fairul82/PythonTestFramework1.0/wiki/For-Beginner-:-How-to-Create-Python-Test-Case-using-Selenium-IDE

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn the question has nothing to do with Selenium IDE.

Comment: @alecxe first line "So the code below is a webdriver python code generated from selenium ide"

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn yeah and this is where it ends :)

Comment: lol... the problem has nothing to do with selenium. the ide was great for generating the code. the problem is how do i get the unittest to create multiple test cases without having to restart the browser. i'll add more to the description to help explain what i mean